# ASP.NET Writing to the Bin directory, access denied when anonymous user

Tags: asp.net

I have a program that creates a small file in the Bin directory for the purpose of tracking a license (that's the intention), all works fine when debugging but I've just realized that when I run it on a IIS server under the anonymous user account (IUSR) the file isn't created as IUSR only has read permission (I know this is correct but drat!).

Can I write to another location under IUSR account or can I run my code under 'Local Service' account?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're impersonating the user, the saving operation is performed with the Application Pool account.

Not sure which IIS you're using but (at least on IIS 6.0), by default, application pools run under the  `Network Service` account so you would need to give write permissions on that folder to that account.

Comment: Hi Claudio, I've placed the code that creates the file in Page_Load of my Default.aspx file, I've not told it to impersonate the user so should my code run under 'Network Service' or should it be added elsewhere? My web.config is using <authentication mode="None"/>. Thanks

Comment: Please add write permissions on the folder where the file is been saved for the user "Network Service"